Publish a sensor's pose in gazebo
I am building a simulation to test a custom SLAM implementation in gazebo. I have a camera sensor attached to a (quadrotor) model. As the model navigates through the world, I want to be able to measure the accuracy of the pose estimated by SLAM against a ground truth value. For that, I assume, an up-to-date reading of the sensor's pose from the simulator will serve well.
Is there a way to create a topic is gazebo that will publish the sensor's current pose in world coordinates?

See my previous answer.
The provided links in that answer are for Fortress, which has some different syntax than the more recent Gazebo versions, due to the rename of 'Ignition' to 'Gazebo Sim'.
So you will need to switch the branch to the one corresponding to your Gazebo version:


Thanks a lot!
One more question. I implemented the publisher as explained in the pose_publisher example and it works as expected. However, the PosePublisher plugin only creates a single topic for model/{name}/pose even with all publish_{tag}_pose options set to true.The names of the options do imply that I should be able to get the pose of a sensor.
These would be the SDF trees for instance
sdf > world > model > link > sensor > plugin doesn't work
sdf > world > model > plugin works
Note: The plugin can only be attached to a <model>

There is only one publisher, publishing pose info for all child entities. See here for more info.
